# Jquery get readout of text area live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if I could get a little help. I want to get a live preview of what is in my text area above it.

Each new line in the text area will display as a list above it, so something like this:

- test
- test2
- test3

Text area:

```
test
test2
test3
```

How I want it to work is that on load it reads the contents of the text area and displays the contents above in a list. Then when the contents of the text area changes it also changes the list above it.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/9sX6X/

```
<h4>Placeholder</h4>
<ul id="tst"></ul>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Test" id="test"></textarea>
```

This is how far I got:

```
$('#test').bind('input propertychange', function() {
      if(this.value.length){
Rerender list to show contents
      }
});
```

This is one of my first scripts so could someone please give me some guidance on how this should be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chc9N/2/)

```
var list = $('#tst');

$('#test').on('keyup', function() {
      list.empty();
      if(this.value.length){
          $.each(this.value.split("\n"), function(i, val){
              list.append($('<li></li>').text(val));
          });
      }
});

$('#test').trigger('keyup'); // required to make it do the update onload
```

Because of my usage of `.text()`, this will handle special characters such as `<` and `>` without a problem. Also note how I have only selected the `<ul>` a single time, instead of re-selecting it over and over.

Side note: as of jQuery 1.7, `.on()` is preferred instead of `.bind()`.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/2/

**CODE**

```
$('#test').bind('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value.length) {
        var inp = this.value.split("\n");
        $("#list").empty();
        for(var x = 0; x < inp.length; x++){
            $("#list").append("<li>"+inp[x]+"</li>")   
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$('#test').on('change', function () {
   var lines = $(this).val().split('\n');

   $('#tst').empty(); 

   for (var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
     $('#tst').append('<li>' +  lines[i] + '</li>');
   }
});
```

Note: this code works on the `change` event of the textarea, thus you need to click outside of the textarea for the event to fire. If you want to do it on every key press, you should change the event from `change` to `keyup`. However, this does lead to far less performance.

You can see the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xv73p/