# Stripping out blank lines from preview on job post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/chc9N/5

```
var list = $('#preview');

$('#requirement').on('keyup', function() {
      list.empty();
      if(this.value.length){
          $.each(this.value.split("\n"), function(i, val){
              list.append($('<li></li>').text(val));
          });
      }
});

$('#requirement').trigger('keyup');
```

What I would like to do is ignore any lines which have been left with a blank space. My issue with this script is that if people keep adding in lots of blank lines between content it starts to get very messy. I want a system where only lines with content show up in the preview above it. Is this possible with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) the value and test if it equals an empty string:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HX7CV/1/)

```
$('#requirement').on('keyup', function() {
      list.empty();
      if(this.value.length){
          $.each(this.value.split("\n"), function(i, val){
              if($.trim(val) != '') {
                  list.append($('<li></li>').text(val));
              }
          });
      }
});
```

Comment: No problem, nice to see my code from a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188902/jquery-get-readout-of-text-area-live) being used :-)